Keras: Conv2D Layer Not Accepting Weights After Image Augmentation Pipeline
I'm encountering a peculiar issue when attempting to load pre-trained weights into a convolutional layer (Conv2D) in a Keras model. The problem arises when I include an image augmentation pipeline using tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing (e.g., RandomCrop, RandomFlip) before the Conv2D layer.
Observed Behavior:

Without the augmentation pipeline, the Conv2D layer loads the weights correctly using layer.set_weights().

When adding the augmentation pipeline before the Conv2D layer, layer.set_weights() throws an error, indicating that the layer doesn't expect to receive weights.

Inspecting the model's layers (via print(model.layers)) doesn't explicitly show the augmentation layers, but the Conv2D layer seems to be initialized differently.


Code:
data_aug = Sequential([
                RandomCrop(height=384, width=384),
                RandomZoom(height_factor=0.1),
                RandomRotation(factor=0.0556),
                Resizing(height=224, width=224)
            ])
            # Variável x_unlabeled armazena o vetor latente da representacao criada (h-last)
            feature_extraction = Sequential()

            #Aplica a augmentation antes de entrar no input
            feature_extraction.add(data_aug) 
    
           # Adiciona a input layer explicitamente
            feature_extraction.add(Input(shape=(224, 224, 1)))
            
            # Loop para adicionar camadas convolucionais e carregar os pesos
            for k in range(n_encoder):
                feature_extraction.add(Conv2D(filters[k], (filter_convolution, filter_convolution), strides=stride,
                                              activation=activation, padding='same'))
                
                feature_extraction.layers[-1].set_weights(autoencoder_model.layers[k + 1].get_weights())
            
            # Add Flatten layer
            feature_extraction.add(Flatten())
            
            # Add Dense layer and set its weights
            feature_extraction.add(Dense(hidden, activation=activation))
            feature_extraction.layers[-1].set_weights(autoencoder_model.layers[k + 3].get_weights())

Error:
Cell In[1], line 233, in Representations.Generate_all(self, stride, activation, filter_convolution, filters, output_activation, size_input_data, n_hidden, n_encoder, kernel_initializer, padding, epochs, verbose, batch_size, seeds_rep, hidden_rep, arch_rep, number_of_repr, const, techs)
    229 for k in range(n_encoder):
    230     feature_extraction.add(Conv2D(filters[k], (filter_convolution, filter_convolution), strides=stride,
    231                                   activation=activation, padding='same'))
--> 233     feature_extraction.layers[-1].set_weights(autoencoder_model.layers[k + 1].get_weights())
    235 # Add Flatten layer
    236 feature_extraction.add(Flatten())

File c:\users\lffon\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py:696, in Layer.set_weights(self, weights)
    694 layer_weights = self.weights
    695 if len(layer_weights) != len(weights):
--> 696     raise ValueError(
    697         f"You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer '{self.name}' "
    698         f"with a weight list of length {len(weights)}, but the layer "
    699         f"was expecting {len(layer_weights)} weights."
    700     )
    701 for variable, value in zip(layer_weights, weights):
    702     if variable.shape != value.shape:

ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer 'conv2d_6' with a weight list of length 2, but the layer was expecting 0 weights.


Put the Input layer BEFORE the augmentation pipeline. Also, if your images are not scaled in the [0.0, 1.0] range you need to include a Rescaling layer in your augmentation pipeline.
